# Populate Pivot Table From Mysql On Php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been struggling on populating pivot table on php from mysql table. I got following code on google but i guess something is wrong with this code

Php CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$q = ($_GET['q']);

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Designation, Department FROM headcount)t PIVOT (Count (Department) FOR Department IN $q) AS pvt";

mysql_select_db('emp_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    echo "Designation :{$row['Designation']}  <br> ".
         "Department : {$row['$q']} <br> ".
        "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Error:

```
Could not get data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PIVOT (Count (Department) FOR Department IN VOC) AS pvt' at line 1
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? An error message for example?

Comment: Your query is not valid.

Comment: Just check your query again, it's just an obvious typo.

Comment: Can anyone help me with query pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting says that there is something wrong in executing your SQL query.

in your SQL statement, try to remove the bold part and execute the php script again.

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Designation, Department FROM
>   headcount)**t** PIVOT (Count (Department) FOR Department IN $q) AS
>   pvt";